# Number to Words Conversion (Indian Rupee) decimal String issue in php

Tags: php, laravel, function, numbers

I using Following function to convert numbers to word Conversion in PHP.

I Expected Result.

one thousand five hundred and forty two Rupees twenty six Paise Only

but, its Display

one thousand five hundred and forty two Rupees two six Paise Only

My Function is :

```
function displaywords($number){
   $no = round($number);
   $point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
   $hundred = null;
   $digits_1 = strlen($no);
   $i = 0;
   $str = array();
   $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
    '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
    '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
    '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
    '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
    '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
    '18' => 'eighteen', '19' =>'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
    '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
    '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
    '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
   $digits = array('', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');
   while ($i < $digits_1) {
     $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
     $number = floor($no % $divider);
     $no = floor($no / $divider);
     $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;


     if ($number) {
        $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
        $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
        $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
            " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
            :
            $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
            . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
            . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
     } else $str[] = null;
  }
  $str = array_reverse($str);
  $result = implode('', $str);


  $points = ($point) ?
    "" . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : ''; 

  if($points != ''){        
  echo $result . "Rupees  " . $points . " Paise Only";
} else {

    echo $result . "Rupees Only";
}

}

$ins=1542.26;

echo displaywords($ins);
```

Comment: What is the value you pass in?

Comment: @KevinKyaw $ins=1542.26;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the code slightly to a more efficient code. (I think).
It uses less variables, no imploding, no array functions, less ifs, and less calculations.

It explodes the number at `.` and makes it an array and handles them seperatly in the same code (`$val`).
Then it takes each number of the string and str_pads it to it's "main number" (don't know a better way of saying it).
So 1526, it looks at the 1, and makes it 1000 with str_pad.
If it's above 90 use both $words and $digits.

This code will also handle numbers like `0.50`, or `10`.

```
function displaywords($number){
    $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
    '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
    '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
    '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
    '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
    '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
    '18' => 'eighteen', '19' =>'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
    '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
    '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
    '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
    $digits = array('', '', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');

    $number = explode(".", $number);
    $result = array("","");
    $j =0;
    foreach($number as $val){
        // loop each part of number, right and left of dot
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);$i++){
            // look at each part of the number separately  [1] [5] [4] [2]  and  [5] [8]

            $numberpart = str_pad($val[$i], strlen($val)-$i, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT); // make 1 => 1000, 5 => 500, 4 => 40 etc.
            if($numberpart <= 20){ // if it's below 20 the number should be one word
                $numberpart = 1*substr($val, $i,2); // use two digits as the word
                $i++; // increment i since we used two digits
                $result[$j] .= $words[$numberpart] ." ";
            }else{
                //echo $numberpart . "<br>\n"; //debug
                if($numberpart > 90){  // more than 90 and it needs a $digit.
                    $result[$j] .= $words[$val[$i]] . " " . $digits[strlen($numberpart)-1] . " "; 
                }else if($numberpart != 0){ // don't print zero
                    $result[$j] .= $words[str_pad($val[$i], strlen($val)-$i, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT)] ." ";
                }
            }
        }
        $j++;
    }
    if(trim($result[0]) != "") echo $result[0] . "Rupees ";
    if($result[1] != "") echo $result[1] . "Paise";
    echo " Only";
}

$ins=1516.16;

echo displaywords($ins);
```

https://3v4l.org/rFvbJ

added some comments to the code.
Noticed it was giving wrong outputs on larger numbers, corrected.

Comment: when i give $ins=1542.58;. its display one thousand five hundred and forty three Rupees Paise Only... fifty eight is missing @Andreas

Comment: @Karthik Have a look at it now.

Comment: echo displaywords(1542.16); its display  "one thousand five hundred forty two Rupees  ten eight Paise Only"

Comment: No it doesn't! https://3v4l.org/58foa it outputs correct `one thousand five hundred forty two Rupees  ten six Paise Only`

Comment: Not Ten Six ... Sixteen Correct

Comment: @Karthik I have updated it to fix numbers below 20. My code still performs better than accepted answer. Mine does not have the extra spacings, and can handle numbers below 1.

Comment: It fails for, 11000.00  Notice: Undefined index: 00 in /in/hUlRH on line 28
one lakh one thousand   Rupees  Only

Comment: @AndyPHP nice catch! Didn't notice that. It was an easy fix, just multiply the string with 1 and it becomes 0 instead of '00'.

Comment: @Andreas its work only php 8.1.12 ?

Answer (score 3):

```
function displaywords($number){
   $no = (int)floor($number);
   $point = (int)round(($number - $no) * 100);
   $hundred = null;
   $digits_1 = strlen($no);
   $i = 0;
   $str = array();
   $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
    '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
    '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
    '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
    '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
    '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
    '18' => 'eighteen', '19' =>'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
    '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
    '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
    '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
   $digits = array('', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');
   while ($i < $digits_1) {
     $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
     $number = floor($no % $divider);
     $no = floor($no / $divider);
     $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;


     if ($number) {
        $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
        $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
        $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
            " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
            :
            $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
            . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
            . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
     } else $str[] = null;
  }
  $str = array_reverse($str);
  $result = implode('', $str);


  if ($point > 20) {
    $points = ($point) ?
      "" . $words[floor($point / 10) * 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : ''; 
  } else {
      $points = $words[$point];
  }
  if($points != ''){        
      echo $result . "Rupees  " . $points . " Paise Only";
  } else {

      echo $result . "Rupees Only";
  }

}


echo displaywords(1542.26);
echo "\n";
echo displaywords(1542.58);
```

Comment: Some explanation perhaps?

Comment: This code does not handle numbers below 1 well. For example: https://3v4l.org/LQKar and creates extra spacing with nubers in even tens ( 10, 20, 30, etc.). https://3v4l.org/lKFTb

Comment: @mokamoto12  echo displaywords(1542.16); its display "one thousand five hundred and forty two Rupees tensix Paise Only"

Comment: @Karthik Sorry for the late reply. maybe fixed it, displaywords(1542.16); is return one thousand five hundred  and forty two  Rupees  sixteen Paise Only

Comment: Still outputs extra spaces and wrong string for numbers below 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');

function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
return;
}
if (error_reporting() & $severity) {
throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
}
}

function convert_number_to_words($number) {

$hyphen      = '-';
$conjunction = ' and ';
$separator   = ', ';
$negative    = 'negative ';
$decimal     = ' point ';
$dictionary  = array(
    0                   => 'zero',
    1                   => 'one',
    2                   => 'two',
    3                   => 'three',
    4                   => 'four',
    5                   => 'five',
    6                   => 'six',
    7                   => 'seven',
    8                   => 'eight',
    9                   => 'nine',
    10                  => 'ten',
    11                  => 'eleven',
    12                  => 'twelve',
    13                  => 'thirteen',
    14                  => 'fourteen',
    15                  => 'fifteen',
    16                  => 'sixteen',
    17                  => 'seventeen',
    18                  => 'eighteen',
    19                  => 'nineteen',
    20                  => 'twenty',
    30                  => 'thirty',
    40                  => 'fourty',
    50                  => 'fifty',
    60                  => 'sixty',
    70                  => 'seventy',
    80                  => 'eighty',
    90                  => 'ninety',
    100                 => 'hundred',
    1000                => 'thousand',
    100000             => 'lakh',
    10000000          => 'crore'
);

if (!is_numeric($number)) {
    return false;
}

if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
    // overflow
    trigger_error(
        'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
    return false;
}

if ($number < 0) {
    return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
}

$string = $fraction = null;

if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
    list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
}

switch (true) {
    case $number < 21:
        $string = $dictionary[$number];
        break;
    case $number < 100:
        $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
        $units  = $number % 10;
        $string = $dictionary[$tens];
        if ($units) {
            $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
        }
        break;
    case $number < 1000:
        $hundreds  = $number / 100;
        $remainder = $number % 100;
        $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    case $number < 100000:
        $thousands   = ((int) ($number / 1000));
        $remainder = $number % 1000;

        $thousands = convert_number_to_words($thousands);

        $string .= $thousands . ' ' . $dictionary[1000];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $separator . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    case $number < 10000000:
        $lakhs   = ((int) ($number / 100000));
        $remainder = $number % 100000;

        $lakhs = convert_number_to_words($lakhs);

        $string = $lakhs . ' ' . $dictionary[100000];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $separator . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    case $number < 1000000000:
        $crores   = ((int) ($number / 10000000));
        $remainder = $number % 10000000;

        $crores = convert_number_to_words($crores);

        $string = $crores . ' ' . $dictionary[10000000];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $separator . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    default:
        $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
        $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
        $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
        try
        {
        $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return "Value too large";
        }
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
            $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
}

if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
    $string .= $decimal;
    $words = array();
    foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
        $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
    }
    $string .= implode(' ', $words);
}

return $string;
}

echo convert_number_to_words(100000000);
?>
```

Comment: The best answer!